# Change CMake RPATH for a single library while keeping others

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, linker, ldd

At the moment I am dealing with some RPATH and runtime linking problem where I need help:

**Situation:**

I have a small application `MyApp` that links against a shared library `MyLibrary`. The `MyLibrary` library uses a PKCS11 shared library from SafeNet to communicate with a PKCS11 USB token. The shared library from this SDK is located in `/opt/safenet/protecttoolkit5/ptk/lib/libcryptoki.so`. The following CMake file is used to create a working application:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13.0)
project(myapp)

# Find the PKCS11 middleware and include it by default
include_directories("/opt/safenet/protecttoolkit5/ptk/include")
link_directories("/opt/safenet/protecttoolkit5/ptk/lib")

# Move all libraries and executables into the same directory so SO/DDL resolvement isn't a problem anymore
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/output)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/output)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/output)

# Define the shared library that uses the cryptoki library
add_library(MyLibrary SHARED)
target_sources(MyLibrary PRIVATE MyLibrary.cpp)
target_link_libraries(MyLibrary PUBLIC cryptoki)
install(TARGETS MyLibrary LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})

# Define the application that uses MyLibrary
add_executable(MyApp MyApp.cpp)
target_link_libraries(MyApp MyLibrary)
install(TARGETS MyApp RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)
```

And `ldd` shows the following dependencies which contains the `/opt/safenet/protecttoolkit5/ptk/lib/libcryptoki.so`:

```
acme@acme:~/Workspace/cmaketest/build$ ldd ./output/MyApp 
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffdc326e000)
        libMyLibrary.so => /home/acme/Workspace/cmaketest/build/output/libMyLibrary.so (0x00007f275575d000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f2755573000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f2755559000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f2755384000)
        libcryptoki.so => /opt/safenet/protecttoolkit5/ptk/lib/libcryptoki.so (0x00007f275500e000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f2754eca000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f2755769000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f2754ebe000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f2754eb8000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f2754e96000)
```

**Problem:**

The application works like expected, but the problem is: The PKCS11 middleware is interchangable via symlink, which in our case is located in `/lib/libcryptoki` (and points to `/usr/lib/libeToken.so` - the USB PKCS11 middleware).

For testing, I don't want to use the middleware in `/opt/safenet/protecttoolkit5/ptk/lib/libcryptoki.so`, but the one in `/lib/libcryptoki.so` - but because the RPATH is set, the library in `/opt/safenet/protecttoolkit5/ptk/lib/libcryptoki.so` is used. How can I point CMake to use this library for runtime (In our Debian build later, we strip away these information anyway, but we need to test/debug the application before packaging)

**What I tried:**

1.) Disabling RPATH or just strip the RPATH away:

```
set(CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH TRUE)
```

This works, but then MyApp can't find MyLibrary although they are located together in the same `output` directory:

```
acme@acme:~/Workspace/cmaketest/build$ ldd ./output/libMyLibrary.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc7bfbf000)
        libcryptoki.so => /lib/libcryptoki.so (0x00007f87c2ae1000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f87c2914000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f87c28fa000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f87c28d8000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f87c28d2000)
        libpcsclite.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcsclite.so.1 (0x00007f87c28c4000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f87c26ed000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f87c25a9000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f87c2e50000)
acme@acme:~/Workspace/cmaketest/build$ ldd ./output/MyApp 
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff8b3c7000)
        libMyLibrary.so => not found
        libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fef18b78000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fef18b5e000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fef18989000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fef18845000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fef18d69000)
```

2.) Remove the `link_directories`, so CMake picks up the shared library `/lib/libcryptoki.so`. The problem is, that CMake follows the symlink and then the ldd dependency `libcryptoki` becomes `libeToken` - the middleware becomes hardcoded:

```
acme@acme:~/Workspace/cmaketest/build$ ldd ./output/MyApp 
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffce2ff5000)
        libMyLibrary.so => /home/acme/Workspace/cmaketest/build/output/libMyLibrary.so (0x00007f0285b07000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f028591d000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f0285903000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f028572e000)
        libeToken.so.10 => /lib/libeToken.so.10 (0x00007f02853e3000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f028529f000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f0285b13000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f028527b000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f0285275000)
        libpcsclite.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcsclite.so.1 (0x00007f0285267000)
```

**Question:**

- Any ideas how I can make attempt 1 working? Or tell CMake not to follow the symlink? Aka use library from X, but set RPATH Y?
- Best without having the need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH and/or strip the information away manually.

Comment: By default, when build binaries (libraries and executables), CMake assigns to them those RPATH, which exactly equal to the directories with the linked libraries. If you don't like those RPATH, then just assign [CMAKE_BUILD_RPATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_BUILD_RPATH.html) variable to the list of desired RPATH. There is also [BUILD_RPATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/BUILD_RPATH.html) property for per-target tuning.

Comment: "... so CMake picks up the shared library `/lib/libcryptoki.so`. The problem is, that CMake follows the symlink ..." - No, CMake doesn't follow the symlink. It is the linker who reads the library file (by following the symlink) and extracts **actual name** of the library - `libeToken.so.10` - from that file. CMake has no control over this linker's behavior.